# How to redirect group of pages to one page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect more than 1000 subpage to one page, I know we can redirect each page but is there any way to do this with single rules?

For example, I have this type of URL

```
/main-page/bla-bla/bla-bla-bla/
/main-page/bla-bla2/bla-bla-blajhj/bmnddbm/
/main-page/bla-bla3/bla-bla-blajhgj/
```

And so on, I want anything after /main-page/***** will redirect to /main-page/

Answer (score 0):

Regex can help:

```
RewriteRule ^/?main-page/.+ /main-page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: you enable rewrite module, set `Allowoverride All`?